# byte[] InputStream converted to String

Tags: java, inputstream

This is my case: I'm using a library for reading files from a respository (I can't modify that library), the library has a method `getContent` that returns a String (it uses `BasicResponseHandler` to convert the response to String), but the repository also contains binary files too, and I need `bytes[]` to save that as a file. I tried using
`content.getBytes("UTF-8")` and it works with text files, but with other files like images, I get a corrupted file.

`BasicResponseHandler` uses this to convert the input to String (charset is UTF-8):

```
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(instream, charset);
CharArrayBuffer buffer = new CharArrayBuffer(i); 
try {
    char[] tmp = new char[1024];
    int l;
    while((l = reader.read(tmp)) != -1) {
        buffer.append(tmp, 0, l);
    }
} finally {
    reader.close();
}
return buffer.toString();
```

Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: The only thing to do is to fix the BasicResponseHandler class and make it return a byte array instead of a String.

Comment: I don't think you can use that library.  If it converts arbitrary `byte[]`s to `String`s with any charset, it'll unavoidably corrupt the contents.

Comment: I think you would need to figure out how they encode the image file into a string in the first place - if you don't know that, then it might now work. Maybe you can try the ASCII encoding?

Comment: Thank you, I will looking for other alternatives.

Answer (score 2):

When you read an image, that isn't a String, and shouldn't be converted.  Simply write the byte[]'s back out to file, and you'll have an image stored in said file.

Comment: The problem is precisely that he doesn't have a byte array, but a String.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you.  Don't convert the buffer into a String.  In this case, I agree with the above comment, you can't use BasicResponseHandler as is.

Comment: I don't use BasicResponseHadler, i had to decompile the library to see how they convert that.. , and I can't modify the library.

Comment: If you use the library, then it's too late; the corruption is done.  You'll have to find a way to not use that library.

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't able to edit the library code being used, I would suggest looking for a new library to use. Perhaps one that doesn't assume anything about the file content type.

Comment: The problem is that it's a local library, but we don't have allow to modificate that.